# Using NSLayoutConstraints to position a view outside the bounds of its superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

So I have a super view called `self.content` and I'm adding 2 subviews to it, namely `self.bg1` and `self.bg2` respectively.  Initially I want `self.bg2` to be sitting right outside the right bound of `self.content`.  Users should be able to call in `self.bg2` using a button.  When the button is tapped `self.bg1` moves to a position such that its right edge is touching the left edge of `self.content`.  Here's the code that I've written, but it seems to only work when the user switches from `self.bg1` to `self.bg2`(doesn't work backwards)

```
//BG1
self.bg1 = [[UIView alloc]init];
[self.bg1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.content addSubview:self.bg1];

//BG2
self.bg2 = [[UIView alloc]init];
[self.bg2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.content addSubview:self.bg2];

self.viewsDictionary = @{@"bg1":self.bg1,
                         @"bg2":self.bg2};
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:[bg1(%f)]",self.view.frame.size.width] options:0 metrics:nil views:self.viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[bg1]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:self.viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:[bg2(%f)]",self.view.frame.size.width] options:0 metrics:nil views:self.viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[bg2]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:self.viewsDictionary]];
//self.bGConstraint is an NSArray
self.bGConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[bg1]-[bg2]" options:0 metrics:nil views:self.viewsDictionary];
[self.view addConstraints: self.bGConstraint];
```

And in the `switchToBG1` method I have:

```
[self.view removeConstraint:[self.bGConstraint objectAtIndex:0]];
self.bGConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[bg1]-[bg2]" options:0 metrics:nil views:self.viewsDictionary];
[self.view addConstraints: self.bGConstraint];
```

Similarly in `switchToBG2`:

```
[self.view removeConstraint:[self.bGConstraint objectAtIndex:0]];
self.bGConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[bg1]-[bg2]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:self.viewsDictionary];
[self.view addConstraints: self.bGConstraint];
```

Finally `layoutIfNeeded` in a `UIView AnimationWithDuration...`

*EDIT:
The animation when switching from BG1 to BG2 (i.e. left to right) is carried out successfully without any error, but when I try to go from right to left (BG2 back to BG1) the system throws me an `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` error message.

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not `removeConstraint:[self.bGConstraint objectAtIndex:0]`. Swap out the constraints completely each time, i.e. `removeConstraints:self.bGConstraint`.

Comment: Have you tested to make sure that both `switchToBG1` and `switchToBG2` are actually being called alternately?

Comment: @matt thanks for answering but it still doesn't work :( and yes i have tons of logging statements :D

Comment: We are still laying the groundwork. I haven't answered! I'm just getting you to look at the possible issues. You are doing the right sort of thing so it's going to turn out to be something very simple and silly when you find it.

Comment: In the logging area it also says `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` Well answering as in...  trying to help?  :P

Comment: Okay, good info. You needed to include that in your question! That is crucial. So now we know that your constraints are wrong - they conflict. That is why nothing is happening. Rewrite your question to state exactly at which stage of the story you see the "unable to satisfy message", please.

Comment: Of course I'm trying to help - that's what we do around here! :)

Comment: OK, let me suggest a new strategy. Up front, store _all_ the constraints that position bg1 and bg2 in for _one_ position in _one_ property, and _all_ the constraints that position them for the _other_ position in _another_ property. Now when the time comes to swap, swap out all the old ones and swap in all the new ones. That way you will not confuse yourself so much.

Comment: Like the structure of my code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p256rotationChangesInterface2/ch19p593rotationChangesInterface/ViewController.swift I have two complete sets of constraints.

Comment: `stringWithFormat:@"H:[bg1(%f)]",self.view.frame.size.width]` That is not how to do this!!!! Use a variable `bg1(width)` and a `metrics` dictionary!

Comment: Also do not have a separate constraint statement setting the width all by itself! You must do it as part of your horizontal positioning, i.e. your last one sets the horizontal position _and_ the width: `"H:|[bg1(width)]-[bg2(width)]"` and use a `metrics` dictionary to define `width`.

Comment: Thanks so much @matt I have absolutely no idea why but it worked after I pre-defined my constraints!!  And ok sounds like I'll need to do some research on metrics cuz I've never used it before :P

Comment: `metrics` is just like what you are doing but they do it for you. You use a name for a number in your string, and then define the name-number pair in the metrics dictionary. Just like the other dictionary you already have.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it! I've given my suggestion as an actual answer. But you should also do the other stuff I suggested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing looks like the right idea, so there is probably just something wrong with your constraint-swapping logic, which causes something in your second constraint to conflict with something in your first set of constraints which are already there. To prevent that easily, structure it this way:

Up front, store *all* the constraints that position `bg1` and `bg2` for *one* position in *one* property, and *all* the constraints that position them for the *other* position in *another* property. Now when the time comes to swap, swap out *all* the old ones and swap in *all* the new ones. That way you will not confuse yourself so much, and you are guaranteed of consistency.

In other words, your code, which switches just one constraint, is trying to be *too clever*. It is better to keep it simple and stupid (and to have it work correctly)!